# vb.net and twitter Auth v2

Tags: vb.net, twitter, oauth-2.0

We are using a winform app that grabs some data from a database and tweets it out.  The tweets always go out using the same account.  This worked fine for years but now the app stopped working because Twitter no longer is supporting v1.1 auth and we need to use v2.  We are using the free version of Twitter so i have deleted my old app in Twitter and created a new one.  I can't find any examples of what the code looks like for the new authentication version.  I'll post the old code to show what was working and perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.  We are using vb.net.  Perhaps i'm not even trying to go about this correctly.   I'm having a hard time following tweeter dev website.  We are only trying to put tweets out on twitter.  We are not trying to respond to them, read them, retweet them.  Looking at this page on [Developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/migrate/manage-tweets-standard-to-twitter-api-v2) it looks like all i should have to do is make my Twitter app belong to a Twitter project, update the credentails and the code should work.  It doesn't, 401 error comes back.  If i'm making this too hard i would love to be redirected.  Thank you

```
 Public Shared Function Tweet(status As String) As String
        Dim mError As String = String.Empty

        Dim boolResult As Boolean = False
        Dim oauth_version As String = "1.0"
        Dim oauth_signature_method As String = "HMAC-SHA1"
        Dim oauth_nonce As String = Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))
        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        Dim oauth_timestamp As String = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString()

        Dim resource_url As String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"  
        'Dim resource_url As String = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets"

        
        'Office info
        Dim oauth_consumer_key As String = "Removed"
        Dim oauth_consumer_secret As String = "Removed"
        Dim oauth_token As String = "Removed"
        Dim oauth_token_secret As String = "Removed"

        Dim baseFormat As String = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}"

        Dim baseString As String = String.Format(baseFormat, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, oauth_version, Uri.EscapeDataString(status))

        Try
            baseString = String.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString))
            Dim compositeKey = String.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret))

            Dim objHasher As HMACSHA1 = New HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey))

            Dim oauth_signature As String = Convert.ToBase64String(objHasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)))

            Dim headerFormat As String = "OAuth oauth_nonce=""{0}"", oauth_signature_method=""{1}"", oauth_timestamp=""{2}"", oauth_consumer_key=""{3}"", oauth_token=""{4}"", oauth_signature=""{5}"", oauth_version=""{6}"""

            Dim authHeader As String = String.Format(headerFormat, Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version))

            Dim postBody As String = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status)


            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)

            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(resource_url), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader)
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

            Dim contentData() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody)
            stream.Write(contentData, 0, contentData.Length)

            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

            boolResult = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            boolResult = False
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Error", ex.ToString())
            mError = ex.Message.ToString
        End Try

        Return mError
    End Function
```